# GCP project created by an app authorized by me, but I do not have access to it?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-cloud-platform, zoho, google-apps-script-api

I'm developing some automation/integration between a CRM software and my google account. I am attempting to use the Google Apps Script API so I can remotely execute functions in Google Apps Script through the integration I'm building from within the CRM software.

The only problem is, when attempting to run a function which calls a GAS function through the API, I get the following error:

"Apps Script API has not been used in project *project number* before or it is disabled. Enable it by visiting https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/script.googleapis.com/overview?project=103424032563 then retry. If you enabled this API recently, wait a few minutes for the action to propagate to our systems and retry."

This would normally be no problem, as I would simply access the GCP portal through the link and enable the GAS API, but when I try to access my project, I don't have access at all, and get the "failed to load data" error.

Further complicating my issue, GCP support will not help because they suspect I am a hacker trying to obtain access to a project that, for all they know, isn't mine.

And because I cannot access this project to authorize the API, I also cannot associate my google script with the same project, as this is a requirement for the Google Apps Script API to function.

I suspect it's the CRM software piece in which I'm developing this integration that is causing this error, (somehow the GCP project is being created by a different user,) but they haven't been all that helpful in determining what's going on.

Have any of you had a similar situation? And, if so, how did you approach solving it?

Comment: Because you need to manually configure the GCP project, the Apps Script project may require you to associate the Apps Script project with a "standard" Google Cloud Platform project.  Did you create a "standard" GCP project for the Apps Script project?  Quote: "you should use a standard GCP project for any application that is complex, commercial quality, or is intended for publication" End quote.  If you can not find a solution to the problem, I would create a new Apps Script file, create a standard GCP project, copy your code over, and start with a new Apps Script file.

Comment: Good point- I did consider this. The problem is, there is no front end within Zoho CRM to associate my code with a different project; the GCP project was automatically created behind the scenes when I created a "Connection," which is basically an automatically managed OAuth connection between Zoho CRM and an external API. It then throws this error, and because I have no authority to view this project, I cannot even associate my google apps script to the same project that the code is associated with.

Answer (score 0):

> Further complicating my issue, GCP support will not help because they
>   suspect I am a hacker trying to obtain access to a project that, for
>   all they know, isn't mine.

Google Support does not refuse to help. They don't accuse you of being a hacker. Google Support can look at the project and see if you have credentials in the project and if you do they can explain how to authorize yourself. However, Google Support requires a support agreement, which is not free. If you do not have one, then you are not entitled to technical support only billing support. Look up your billing account ID and send a request for billing support. Your billing account will also show you which projects are linked to your billing account.

The issue is that you are trying to access the wrong Project ID. Figure out what is the correct Project ID. If you have the Cloud SDK installed execute this command `gcloud projects list` and this will tell you which projects your credentials have access to.

Comment: I understand I am trying to access the wrong project ID; the problem is that I know the gcloud projects list command wont result in the project I'm interested in: I called billing support, and they confirmed that none of the accounts I'm associated with own or have permissions for the project. I also asked about technical support and the representative said that I could get it, although they may not be able to help because there's no way to confirm my involvement with the project. There's some ambiguous owner of the project; I'm not allowed to know their info because of privacy reasons.

Comment: If Google cannot help you, how do you expect StackOverflow to help you? If you do not have rights to a project, you are out of luck unless that account owner allows you access.

Comment: I know that; I'm just confused about how it's possible that a GCP project created through my own application (OAuth and all authorized through me,) gives me a reference to a project which I do not have access to whatsoever. I would just like some insight on how these projects are created behind the scenes and if anyone has a similar situation/advice on if they've ever dealt with such a situation.

Comment: Reread your question from my viewpoint. There are few details on exactly what you did to get into your situation. I understand Google IAM extremely well and I cannot guess what you did. The fact that you can see a Project Number means nothing. What is important is having rights to that project.

Comment: I will edit my question to be more specific and lengthy; although It will be specific to the software In which I'm developing. I was trying to avoid being too specific, but it's probably necessary for you to determine exactly whats happening.